# Parse array from web page (Python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I have a webpage, that contains information as:

> [{'name':'Apple', 'q': 10},{'name':'Banana', 'q':9}]

How to parse this data from web page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a list of dictionaries (mapping type), so to parse you can use:

```
l = [{'name':'Apple', 'q': 10},{'name':'Banana', 'q':9}]

for dictionary in l:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print(key, value)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name Apple
q 10
name Banana
q 9
```

As stated John in a commnet, in case that is an string:

```
import json

s = "[{'name':'Apple', 'q': 10},{'name':'Banana', 'q':9}]"
l = json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))

for dictionary in l:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Same output.

Comment: If it's contained in a webpage as stated, then it can't be a native Python dict; it would have to be a text representation of a dict.

Comment: @JohnGordon You are right. I edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are dealing with a dictionary in Python. Lets assume the name of the dictionary be **`Nurislom_Turaev`**. So to parse/print the elements you can do the following:

```
Nurislom_Turaev = [{'name':'Apple', 'q': 10},{'name':'Banana', 'q':9}]

for dictionary in Nurislom_Turaev:
    for name,q in dictionary.items():
        print (name, "=>", q)
```

Console Output:

```
name => Apple
q => 10
name => Banana
q => 9
```